# GCP Storage Resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Hello and good morning!

After I took a closer look at my Google Cloud Console as a hobby developer, I noticed a high memory requirement, which I could not compare with my Firebase Storage. In the console I was able to see that I had some artifacts and GCF sources. However, these have not been modified for a long time - although I re-uploaded all cloud functions this morning as a test.

Can I just delete these buckets (see screenshot)?

[image]

Comment: If you remove those bucket, you won't be able to get the source code from Cloud Functinos. If you have containers, you will lost the contents of the containers. So, you can delete those bucket but be aware of the impact of that deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove those bucket, you won't be able to get the source code from Cloud Functinos. If you have containers, you will lost the contents of the containers. So, you can delete those bucket but be aware of the impact of that deletion